# How to add overlay view over other view in android?

Tags: android, view, overlay

I want to put button above image view.

How can i do this?

(Please, don't offer to set Background, cause i need ImageView)

Answer (score 11):

Set as background!

Just kidding... what you need is put your views inside a `RelativeLayout`. Something like will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:text="blah blah"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice the use of params like `layout_alignParentLeft` which are used to position the view where you want.

Comment: You can also use merge (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) or a framelayout (http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)

Comment: The above link is dead now, try this instead: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Cristian's answer. but also,
If you need button's action listener you can add onClick method to your imageView without using button.

And also ImageButton. I hope this answer shows some path to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me with both `ImageView` and `Button` inside `RelativeLayout`:

```
 <Button android:layout_centerInParent="true">
```

...