# Overlap Views in layout of Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create layout having logo (small logo than screen) on the centre of the screen (horizontally & vertically) and on the top of the centred logo, I want to have a full screen (fill_parent) LinearLayout having ListView in it.

Want to keep ListView little transparent to keep my logo visible, looks like a watermark.

Can any one please tell me that what could be the XML for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for logo to be at centre use `android:gravity="center"` and also set `opacity="translucent"` and use it in a frame layout and also use overlay concept.

You can also check [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790511/how-to-add-overlay-view-over-other-view-in-android).

Answer (score 2):

Use Framelayout,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

You can even use relative layout to overlap views.