# How to add a custom view on an imageview in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-custom-view

I am making an android App in which the user picks and loads a image from the gallery. I am done with loading my image in an image view. There is a button above the image view. When the user clicks the button a rectangle has to be drawn on the image with default position and dimensions. The user can re-size this rectangle by clicking on the sides and also drag the rectangle to any point in the image view. I did some research on Google and stack overflow to find that I need to create a custom view for my rectangle and draw it over the imageview. The solutions that I found have shown how to make a custom view and how to add touch events to that. But the problem is I didn't find a solution to how to add myCustomView on the image view in an activity. Please help me clearing this doubt.

Below is my main activity on which there is a button (Load Image) User clicks on it to load an image from the gallery. The path of the image is sent to the other activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("key", picturePath);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
}
}
```

Below is the activity where the image is displayed on the imageview and the mycustomview has to be called.

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity {
 Paint paint = new Paint();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String value = bundle.getString("key");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(value);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);


    Button buttonExit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonExit);
    buttonExit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button buttonDrawRect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DrawRect);
    buttonDrawRect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {


        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want the 'imageView' to resize when you click on the sides.right??

Comment: No look at the image in the edit of my question.. I just want a red rectangle to be drawn over my image.. to focus some specific part of the image. I want the rectangle to be resized and be dragged but not the imageView..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through these links. May help you

[Overlapping Views in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961944/overlapping-views-in-android)

[How to add overlay view over other view in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790511/how-to-add-overlay-view-over-other-view-in-android)

Also check the linked posts also

Hope this may help you

Comment: The customView has to be added dynamically.. i dont know if this would work. I just want to know how to add mycustomView in the activity, over my image view..

Answer (score 0):

Basically draw the image on a SurfaceView.  Then for whatever goes over it set android:background="@null" for transparency.  Thats how you could layer something like that.  Do not set to null but to @null.

Comment: my question is how to get it over the image at first place. because i havve my rectangle as a another view. I want to add that view to my imageview.